# How to validate email and confirm email field (not case sensitive) in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have two fields-email and confirm email.I am trying to do validation for email field and Confirm Email field.The validation is working but not when the same email id is entered in different case i.e "Email" in "uppercase" and "Confirm email" in "lower case".

My code-

```
<label>Email</label>
<md-input type="email" placeholder="email" [(ngModel)]="form.email"></md-input>

<label>Confirm Email</label>
<md-input type="Confirm email" placeholder="Confirm email" [(ngModel)]="form.ConfirmEmail></md-input>
<span *ngIf="form.email!=form.confirmEmail">email and confirm email don't match</span>
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing wrong but is missing toLowerCase()

Comment: If i add toLowerCase(), it validates only when email is eneterd in lower case else it throws error.

Comment: Then call a function from the ngIf, give it the passwords and return whether they are equal in lower case.  Don't have to change the originals